# Finding the value of a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code.

```
$stmt4 = $conn->prepare("SELECT likedFour FROM UserData WHERE username = 'jim'");
```

Right now, this should find the value of the row LikeFour when username = jim.

I have this if statement.

```
if ($stmt4 == '') {
}
```

Shouldn't this check if that value is empty?
It's not working.

This is the full code.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$username);
//$username = $_POST["username"];
$username ="jim";
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT likedOne FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$stmt1->bind_param('s',$username);
//$username = $_POST["username"];
$username ="jim"; 


 echo "debug 2";
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0){ // username not taken
    echo "debug 2.5";
    die;

}else{
$result = mysqli_num_rows($stmt1);
echo "debug 2.7";
echo var_dump($stmt1);
    if ($stmt1 == 00000){
    echo "debug 3";
        $sql =  $conn->prepare("UPDATE UserData SET likedOne=? WHERE username=?");
        $sql->bind_param('ss',$TUsername,$Username);
//      $TUsername = $_POST["TUsername"];
//      $Username = $_POST["username"];
        $TUsername = "test";
        $Username = "jim";

    }
}
```

Comment: I gave up and deleted my answer. It was getting tedious.

Comment: r u giving up on me?

Comment: There is some disconnect that you're not getting. I think you should go  look at some examples of mysqli prepared statements and try again.

Comment: You need to post the whole block of code which sends the query and gets the results.

Comment: ok. will do right now

Comment: i posted the full code

Comment: Pls help me. I posted the full code

Comment: This question is clearly under-researched.

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: @RonArel He means that it doesn't look like you researched online how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
$stmt4 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username = 'jim'");
//This should grab the entire row where username == jim
```

Then

```
if(!$stmt4[likedFour]){
echo "Nothing has been found";
}
```

If everything else is all good that should work perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Try placing two equals signs instead of one.  The first equals sign indicates that you are setting the condition while the second equals indicates you are checking to see if something is equal to the first variable.